# every ordered ﬁeld $K$ has a natural valuation $v$, whose residue ﬁeld is an archimedean ordered ﬁeld.

Tags: valuation-theory, ordered-fields

Natural valuation has a convex valuation ring, in fact the valuation ring is the convex hull of $\mathbb{Z}$.

How to prove that every ordered ﬁeld $K$ has a natural valuation $v$, whose residue ﬁeld is an archimedean ordered ﬁeld.

Comment: Well you can first try to prove that the convex hull of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$ is a valuation ring of $K$.

Comment: There is a theorem that gives that result right away. Convex hull of any subring in ordred field K is valuation ring. Therefore this one too.

Comment: Okay, then do you know how the order on this residue field is defined? If so, given $x \in \operatorname{Hull}(\mathbb{Z})$, can you find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\overline{x} \leq \overline{n}$? (where $\overline{a}= a+\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of the valuation ring)

Comment: I know that $P=\{\bar a : a\in \mathbb{Z} , a\geq 0 \}$ is an ordering in residue field. How to use it to find $n$?

Comment: Correction: $a$ in ordering P is in convex hull of $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $P$ is the positive cone in the residue field so you want to find $n$ with $\overline{n}-\overline{a} \in P$. What does this mean for $a,n$?

Comment: I have got that for $a$ and $n$  this means that $n<z+a$ where $z$ is some nenegative integer. Is this correct? What should I take as n now? or I can say that for such $n$ as above $\bar n - \bar a \in P$ holds?

Comment: Yes and $0 \leq n-a <z$ which gives as that $a \leq n <z+a$ for some positive integer $z$ and such $n$ can always be found. Am I correcct? Now I just go backwards in my proof?

Comment: This is the spirit but it is actually simpler. The map $\overline{.}$ is a ring morphism so in particular we have $\overline{n} - \overline{a} = \overline{n-a}$, which is in $P$ if and only if $a \leq n$. Thus you are just looking for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $a \leq n$. Why should this exist?

Comment: I am not sure but could such $n$ exist because convex hull of $Z$ has archimedean property?

Comment: Yes it does. How do you define the convex hull of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$?

Comment: As a set of all elements $x$ from $K$ such that there exists some integer $m$ in $Z$ that $|x|\leq m$ holds.

Comment: Yes, so in particular there is $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a\leq m$ so $\overline{a} \leq \overline{m}=m.\overline{1}$. This proves that the residue field is archimedean.